# Сортировка массива

Tags: php

Как отсортировать по ключевому полю "SORT" средствами php

Array
(

```
[11] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => 1 элемент
        [SORT] => 5
        [VALUES] => Array
            (
                [105] => Array()
                [106] => Array()
            )

    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => 2 элемент
        [SORT] => 1
        [VALUES] => Array
            (
                [115] => Array()
                [146] => Array()
            )

    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => 3 элемент
        [SORT] => 6
        [VALUES] => Array
            (
                [117] => Array()
                [118] => Array()
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно посредством [array_multisort](http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php)

```
$toSort = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
{
    $toSort[$key] = $val['sort'];
}
array_multisort($toSort, SORT_ASC, $array );
```

как то так(не проверял)

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно сделать пользовательскую сортировку с помощью функции usort().

Comment: тогда уже лучше uasort(), чтобы сохранять связь ключ - значение

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php